# Can't connect to a PG database from MicroOLAP, but can connect from SSH?

Tags: postgresql

I'm able to connect to my PGSQL database from SSHv2.

But when I try to do the same thing on MicroOLAP Database Designer, I get this message:

(Note: **From my college PC, I can connect. But I can't connect from home.**)
[image]

My configuration:

[image]
[image]

Here's me on arka.foi.hr via SSHv2 (accessible from home):

[image]

Comment: you should show also pg_hba.conf it is most important information in connection settings.

Comment: Any improvement on this?

Comment: Nope. I asked a colleague on college, and he can't connect either. But I will accept your answer since it's technically correct :).

Comment: My problem doesn't really exist. I posted the question in belief that it was my fault I can't connect, which is not true - the administrator disabled external connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error dialog it is clear that something around your connection is wrong.

First be sure that everything you included here matches: you have an error about localhost and port 3082 and you present a connection dialog with a foreign host and port 5432.

Then you have to teach PostgreSQL that it should accept connections from your home.  This can be done via the `pg_hba.conf` file.  You will need a line added like this (the header is already there) - if you don't have access to it, ask the person in charge of it to do this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
host    dnizetic        dnizetic        161.53.120.19/32        md5
```

Comment: Do you mean teaching my local PGSQL or remote PGSQL? Because I can't change pg_hba.conf on the remote machine - I don't "own" the server's PGSQL. (I also looked for such file on my machine, and I can't find it - but I doubt you meant that).

Comment: The presented error matches the input images I've uploaded. I checked this twice.

Comment: @Tool Is your local machine at home arka.foi.hr?  If not, then at least one of us don't understand something :)  All in all, do you want to connect to your local PostgreSQL or the remote one?

Comment: The remote one. No, my local machine is localhost (127.0.0.1). arka.foi.hr is a remote IP.

Comment: @Tool Then you have to ask the admin to do that, or (if possible) connect to a suitable VPN before trying to connect to the DB.

Comment: Could you also explain to me why I'm able to do a SSH login to arka.foi.hr (from my home), but I can't connect to the DB with SSH tunneling in MicroOLAP? What's the difference - protocol / port?

Comment: Is the SSH tunneling correctly configured? You haven't showed us the MicroOLAP tunneling configuration.

Comment: @ypercube Hmm.  Is it possible that the problem is the tunneling and everything else is OK?  Didn't tought of that before.

Comment: on @ypercube's comment: leave SSH tunneling as it is now and try to set `localhost` as host instead of arka.foi.hr.